# count array value bug

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

**Hi I need help please i need to fix this code so it count the value only once**

**for exmaple**

input:

25

38 25 36 4 1 1 10 37 45 21 37 42 21 1 50 9 50 42 6 39 10 14 17 11 20

10

36 42 2 15 28 42 3 23 8 50

output:

4

the answer here should be 4 not 7.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, m, count = 0;
    int array[1000];
    int subarray[1000];

    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    scanf("%d", &m);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &subarray[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (array[i] == subarray[j])
                count++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", count);


}
```

Comment: Your logic for checking is flawed, as the inner loop will go out of bounds of `subarray` if `n > m`. A couple of minutes with a debugger would have told you that.

Comment: can you add the question and the purpose of the code? its hard to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: An example with less than 25 and 10 would make it easier to help

Comment: My recommendation is that you *sort* the first array, remove consecutive duplicates, and then use binary search to find each number from the "subarray". You should possibly sort and remove duplicates from the "subarray" as well. (The sorting is needed for binary search to work, and also makes is much easier to remove duplicates.)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Once arrays sorted, no real need to remove duplicates, just skip duplicates during the compare as they are easy to find since they are adjacent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution, using functions and qsort.

(untested code)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int binarySearch(int arr[], int l, int r, int x) { 
    if (r >= l) { 
        int mid = l + (r - l) / 2; 
        if (arr[mid] == x) 
            return mid; 
        if (arr[mid] > x) 
            return binarySearch(arr, l, mid - 1, x); 
        return binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, r, x); 
    } 
    return -1; 
}  

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
   return (*(int*)a > *(int*)b) - (*(int*)a < *(int*)b);
}

int main() {
    int n, m, count = 0;
    int array[1000];
    int subarray[1000];

    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    qsort(array, n, sizeof(int), cmpfunc); // O(n lg n)

    scanf("%d", &m);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &subarray[i]);
        int result = binarySearch(arr, 0, n - 1, x); // O(lg n)
        if (result != -1)
          count++;
    } // O(m lg n)
    
    printf("%d\n", count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the matched values in third array as following and
check if the new value is found before or not

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int n, m, count = 0;
 int array[1000];
 int subarray[1000];
 int result[1000];
 scanf("%d", &n);

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
 }

 scanf("%d", &m);

 for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
 {
    scanf("%d", &subarray[i]);
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        if (array[i] == subarray[j]){
            int isFound=0;
            for(int k=0;k<count;k++){
                if(result[k]==array[i])
                    isFound=1;
            }
            if(isFound==0){
                result[count]==array[i];
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}

printf("%d\n", count);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a boolean variable to check if the elements of array 1 exist in the array 2 ,if not ,i will copied it to array 3

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>//header how found the booleen variable

int main()
{
     int n,m;
     do
     {
         printf("Give me the length of array 1 :");
         scanf("%d",&n);
     }while(n<1);

     int T1[n];//declaration of Array 1
     do
     {
         printf("Give me the length of array 2 :");
         scanf("%d",&m);
     }while(m<1);

     int T2[m];//declaration of Array 2

     printf("The fill of Array 1:\n\n");

     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
         scanf("%d",&T1[i]);
     }

     printf("The fill of Array 2:\n\n");

     for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
     {
         scanf("%d",&T2[j]);
     }
     int T3[n+m];//declaration of Array 3

     bool found=false;//declaration of booleen variable
     int k=0;
  
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     {found=false;
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
              if(T1[i]==T2[j])
              {
                   found=true;
              }
        }
         if(found==true)
         {
             T3[k]=T1[i];
             k++;
         }
     }
     printf("\nThe number of elment duplicate is :%d\n",k);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> so it count the value only once

With minimal impact to OP's code and without re-ordering input:

- Check if the `subarray[]` value already occurred within itself.
- When `subarray[]/array[]` values match, quit looking.

---

```
for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
  bool unique_subarray_value = true;
  for (int earlier = 0; earlier < j; earlier++) {
    if (subarray[earlier] == subarray[j])
      unique_subarray_value = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (unique_subarray_value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (array[i] == subarray[j]) {
        count++;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

A fast approach would sort the arrays and then walk them

```
// Pseudo code
sort array[n]    with qsort()
sort subarray[m] with qsort()

// walk the arrays looking for matches
i = 0;
j = 0;
while (i < n && j < m) {
  if (array[i] == subarray[j]) {
    count++;
    while (i + 1 < n && array[i] == array[i+1]) i++;
    while (j + 1 < m && subarray[j] == subarray[j+1]) j++;
  }
  if (array[i] < subarray[j]) i++;
  else j++;
}
```